# PhpStorm and other Tools in a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I am developing php applications at my work. 
The development server runs in a ubuntu vm, but on the host machine runs windows 7 os.
I keep running into problems with windows as a development environment and i am missing
some linux features.  Unfortunately, I can not install another operating system on the host.
Now I wonder if I should install all my dev tools (like phpstorm) in another virtual machine
and do my work there. Does it make sense or will i get performance issues?

Comment: Your question seems off-topic - please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. You should visit one of the other http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: It is not adviseable to work within a VM, I believe that if you code on windows, but test (one way or another) on the virtual machine you will find it very easy to identify problems. If you can mention specific problems you are experiencing, I would try to suggest ways you could go around them

Comment: please consider accepting my answer if it answered your question or upvote if it was helpful in someway.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use-case for [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/).

> Create and configure lightweight, reproducible, and portable development environments.
>   *From the official website*.

It can be controlled with PhpStorm and it is perfectly lightwight.

I am using PhpStorm, Vagrant & Puppet with nginx, php and mysql, XDebug and I am quite happy with it, quite powerful and very easy to deploy.

### EDIT

And this is awesome blog post by **James McFadden** on [Using Vagrant and Puppet to build a PHP, Nginx and MySQL environment](http://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/using-vagrant-and-puppet-to-build-a-php-nginx-and-mysql-environment/) and you can find numerous others with apache or any other tool you might need.

DECLAIMER: The step with replacing `my.cnf` didn't work for me so I could advice you to just skip it.